# The total number of subsets of a set of size 1001 is odd

Tags: combinatorics

Is this true or false? I also need an explanation as to how we can get the subsets.

Comment: Hint: look up "cardinality of the power set".

Comment: Take a subset $A_1$ and pair it up with its complement. Take another subset $A_2$ not already considered and pair it up with its complement. Continue...

Comment: A set containing all subsets of a set A is called a power set. It always has even cardinality, except when A is an empty set. So, false.

Comment: @DavidMitra: of course, you are assuming $1001 > 0$, otherwise for some $n$ $A_n$ equals its own complement... ;)

Comment: Rok Kralj: the power set of the empty set is the empty set, which has cardinality zero, an even number.

Comment: @DavidG: The power set of the empty set is the set *containing* the empty set, which has cardinality one.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're absolutely right

Answer (score 8):

Match each element of the set with a $0$ or a $1$.  Each arrangement of $1001$ $0$s and $1$s represents a subset, where a $1$ means that that element is in the subset and a $0$ means that element is not in the subset.

There are $2^{1001}$ arrangements of $1001$ $0$s and $1$s, so there are $2^{1001}$ subsets of a set with $1001$ elements.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{1001}\binom{1001}{k}=2^{1001}$$

Comment: With the proper interpretation of $\binom{1001}{k}$, that works, too :-)

Comment: is the statement false?